# Django Static Precompiler not compiling files?

Tags: python, django, django-static-precompiler

[Django static precompiler](http://django-static-precompiler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) does not seem to be working with `scss` files for me. I already checked if i had the compiler installed and my settings for django are are follows

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'static_precompiler',
    'cms',
]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'static_precompiler.finders.StaticPrecompilerFinder',
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "static"
```

and i am calling the same from django template as follows

```
{% load compile_static %}
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Spacemailer</title>
    {% block seo %}
    {% endblock %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style/main.scss' | compile %}" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

There are no errors whatsoever. The output is the same `scss` file with no compilations being made. Can someone point out what am i doing wrong with the same ? or some alternatives that will support compiling `scss` as well as `coffee` scripts

Comment: Do you have DEBUG set to true? Some precompilers won't work in that case, don't know about this one tbh.

Comment: i tried with both options in `DEBUG`

Answer (score 0):

By default the compilation should be done at run time serving the template with 
`compile`filter.

```
{% static "js/alert.es6"|compile %}
```

Renders

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="/static/COMPILED/js/alert.js"></script>
```

If your using a different storage and `STATIC_PRECOMPILER_DISABLE_AUTO_COMPILE` is `True` compile using `compilestatic` before `collectstatic`

Verify the [Compiler configuration](https://django-static-precompiler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#sass-scss)

```
STATIC_PRECOMPILER_COMPILERS = (
       ('static_precompiler.compilers.SCSS', {
        "executable": "/usr/bin/sass",
        "sourcemap_enabled": True,
        "compass_enabled": True,
        "load_paths": ["/path"],
        "precision": 8,
        "output_style": "compressed",
    }),
)
```